# JS for -loop always use last element - scope issues

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, iife

```
var url_array = ["ulr1", "ulr2", "ulr3", "ulr4", "ulr5"];

var img = document.createElement('img');

for (i = 0; i < url_array.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "div"+i);
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(div);

    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.width = ImageWidth+5+"px";
    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.height = ImageHeight+5+"px";

    console.log("\ncreate all the DIVs. \nFor loop count: "+i);

    img.src = loadImage(url_array[i], ImageWidth, ImageHeight);

    try{throw img}
    catch(c_img) {

        document.getElementById('div'+i).appendChild(c_img);

        console.log("after load, and append, in Catch: "+img.src);
        console.log("div NR = "+document.getElementById('div'+i).id);
        console.log(document.getElementById('div'+i).childNodes.length);
    } //catch
} // FOR

function loadImage(URL, h, w)
{
    console.log("loadImage callaed with URL = "+URL);
    return url = URL+Date.now().toString(10);
}
```

For-Loop is supposed to retrieve urls address of an images (from camera) and append them to DIV. DIV and IMGs are created on the fly. Problem is that only last DIV become image holder.

I am using catch-try to force execute code immediately so each separate Div+i will have distinctive image. Also construction like this one (immediately invoked function expression):

```
(function(){
  something here;
  })();
```

for creating "private" scope gives no hope. Either "Let" - which supposed to define variable locally is not helping. *My knowledge here is limited and I'm relying on data found on web site (can give link later if it is not against rules).

Output of console.log() is not helping much.
Everything goes as it should, except for the childNodes.length which is 1 for each for-loop iteration - that means each DIV have its IMG child I guess... If so - why I can't see them?

I feel I am close to what I want to achieve - using Intervals() refresh each DIV with new camera snapshot, but I need to solve this current issue.

Example of code ready to use:
js.js:

```
var url_array = [
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg",
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg",
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg"
];

var ImageWidth = 640;
var ImageHeight = 480;

var img = document.createElement('img');

for (i = 0; i < url_array.length; i++){

    var div = document.createElement('div');//.setAttribute("id", "div0");
    div.setAttribute("id", "div"+i);
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(div);

    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.width = ImageWidth+5+"px";
    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.height = ImageHeight+5+"px";
    var color = ((Math.floor(Math.random() * (16777215)) + 1).toString(16)); // from 1 to (256^3) -> converted to HEX
    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.background = "#"+color;


    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.width = ImageWidth+5+"px";
    document.getElementById('div'+i).style.height = ImageHeight+5+"px";

    console.log("\ncreate all the DIVs. \nFor loop count: "+i);

    img.src = loadImage(url_array[i], ImageWidth, ImageHeight);

    try{throw img}
    catch(c_img) {

        document.getElementById('div'+i).appendChild(c_img);

        console.log("after load, and append, in Catch: "+img.src);
        console.log("div NR = "+document.getElementById('div'+i).id);
        console.log(document.getElementById('div'+i).childNodes.length);
    } // catch
} // FOR

function loadImage(URL, h, w)
{
    console.log("loadImage callaed with URL = "+URL);
    return url = URL+"?auto=compress&h="+h+"&w="+w;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<STYLE>

div#main {
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
}
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript">

function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can create a working code snippet... that would be easy to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
```

is *outside* the loop - you're only ever creating one `img`. When `appendChild` is called on an element that already exists in the DOM (such as on the second, third, fourth, etc iteration), the element gets *removed* from its previous location and inserted into the new location.

Create the image inside the loop instead, and try not to implicitly create global variables - when declaring new variables, always use `let` or `const`.

Also, when you do

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

you have a reference to the `div` you just created - there's no need to assign an `id` to it in order to select it with

```
document.getElementById('div'+i)
```

in below lines *in the same scope*. Instead, just keep referencing the `div`:

```js
const ImageWidth = 200;
const ImageHeight = 200;
const main = document.getElementById('main');
var url_array = ["ulr1", "ulr2", "ulr3", "ulr4", "ulr5"];

for (let i = 0; i < url_array.length; i++){
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  main.appendChild(div);
  div.style.width = ImageWidth+5+"px";
  div.style.height = ImageHeight+5+"px";
  img.src = loadImage(url_array[i], ImageWidth, ImageHeight);
  div.appendChild(img);
}
console.log(main.innerHTML);

function loadImage(URL, h, w) {
  return URL+Date.now().toString(10);
}
```

```css
div#main {
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Comment: It works! I feel a bit ashamed to admit - I was trying to solve this particular problem for like 2 days. Initially I was thinking that creating img object has to be done outside - and then dynamically change content of img each iteration of for-loop. Thank You very much for the help!